# Change a string with backward slashes to forward slashes

Tags: regex, string, text, replace

I have a string in the format of "c:\replaceallslashes\directory1\subdirectory1\etc\etc\file.html" in a large number of files.  All the backslashes in these strings need be changed to forward slashes so that the path can become a URL.  I want to change this via find & replace in a text or regex editor, but don't want to accidentally replace any backslashes outside the string that may occur in the documents.

How should I construct the find and replace command?

**Edit**: just to be clear, I am looking for regex strings for both the "find" and "replace" fields.  The answer below only gives the "find" command.

Comment: You should add some sample text which contains examples of things which should be replaced as well as things which should not be.

Comment: Let's assume the "directory" part of  c:\directory" is a very unique word that will not be encountered anywhere else in the files.  I can give it a unique name just for the purposes of this exercise, e.g. "c:\replaceallslashes\x\y\z\file.html"

Answer (score 0):

A very rudimentary Windows path regex would look something like:

```
[a-z]:\\(?:[a-z0-9_-]+\\?)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/g1hubs/1

The issue is that Windows filenames are only restricted from using `\/:*?"<>|` so there's only a small fraction of chars which tell you that something is definitely not a path. So my example assumes that you only have alphanumeric paths which may or may not include underscores and dashes.

Comment: And how do you replace backslashes with forward slashes?

Comment: What do you enter in the "Replace" field?